# c++ :std::bad_alloc when passing class object as a parameter

Tags: c++, object, parameters

i am trying to pass class object as  a parameter **gameobject**
but i am getting this error

ERROR:
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc**

this is some code :

```
vector<gameobject*> objects;

void addObject(gameobject* object)
    {
        objects.push_back(object);
    }
// in another class 

gameobject* pla = new player(32,32);

hand->addObject(pla); //  the function above ----> here i get the error
```

thank you

**edit** : 
the error is when i call the function it doesn't even enter it

Comment: Looks like you put extra comma after the variable declaration `gameobjext* pls; =`

Comment: As defined here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/bad_alloc/ , try doing try and catch and see what does ba.what() says

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  Pushing a pointer into a vector won't give `std::bad_alloc` (unless you are out of memory), so the error is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: yes idon't know what is it

Comment: and  the error is when i give the parameter it doesn't even enter the unction

Comment: What is `hand`?

Comment: a class that has the addobject function